# Is there a way to search for an element type in Sparx Enterprise Architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect

There doesn't appear to be a way in the model search feature to limit results to a specific type e.g. Class, Node, etc. Is there a way to achieve this? I know I can craft a SQL query however an unable to find the correct table name.

**EDIT**

It appears that I can do the following

`Select *, Object_Type AS CLASSTYPE, Name from t_object Where Object_Type="Node"`.

It seems that Sparx don't appear to have documented `Object_Type` as it displays as `Type` in their documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard way of narrowing the results of a built-in search by entering something in the Search Term box.

If you create a search using the Query Builder, you can specify that the search should only return elements of certain types. In the Add Filters dialog, the element type is referred to as `ObjectType`.

It is possible to utilize SQL string manipulation functions to implement an SQL query which breaks down the `<Search Term>` into parts according to some syntax you decide on, allowing you to specify both a name and an element type, say (but none of the built-in searches do this). This is not possible using the Query Builder.

If you create your own SQL search query, as you've noted, `t_object.Object_Type` contains the element's type.

Regarding the documentation, it's only the database schema that is undocumented. The `Type` field you refer to is from the Object Model API, and in that API, the attribute is indeed called Type.

In addition, all classes in the API contain an attribute `ObjectType`, which identifies the data type. These values are from the `ObjectType` enumeration type, and include `otAttribute`, `otDiagram`, `otElement`, `otRepository`, etc.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't appear to be clear though how I can search for a given element type e.g. node using the model search feature and not utilize SQL

Comment: What do you mean by `identifies the data type`?

Comment: All data types in the API have this (static) member, whose only use is to distinguish between the data types. Most of the time you don't need to check it, but there are occasions when you get an anonymous object (eg Repository.GetTreeSelectedObject). For a usage example, create a Browser Script and look at the code that's created for you.