# Documentation about the internal schema to help build custom SQL Queries?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'm trying to write some custom queries, but I can't seem to find the documetation for the schema of the tables used internally by enterprise architect.

A comment in the question for [Is there a way to search for an element type in Sparx Enterprise Architect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19481567/is-there-a-way-to-search-for-an-element-type-in-sparx-enterprise-architect) indicates "the database schema is undocumented".

I'm trying to avoid investing my time digging through the schema by hand so I can get to the work of writing the query.

If Sparx has not documented this, has any done the investigation?

Comment: My book Inside EA is the only source: http://liquit.biz/brain/books.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing is to reverse engineer the database in EA, or use a tool that reads in the database structure.
Then you might want to read Thomas Kilians book [Inside Enterprise Architect](https://leanpub.com/InsideEA)

But mostly it's rather self-explanatory. It is a really simple database schema.
Having a profiler around (such as the one in SQL Server) that records all SQL queries executed by EA often helps to quickly figure out where EA hides a certain property.